# Read and write from a remote PC to a shared network with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read a file from a remote machine, and then what I read, write it in a shared folder in network. This is my code.

```
Write-Host "Remote copy a file" 
$username = 'Usuario' 
$password = 'Password' 

$myfile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\user.txt") ;
$Escribir={[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("\\192.x.x.x\foreach\54.txt", $args)} ;
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw) 
$servers = Get-Content C:\Users\Agent\Desktop\pcs
foreach($server in $servers) { 
$s = New-PSSession -computerName $server -credential $cred 
Write-Host "PC name: $server ..." -ForegroundColor GREEN -Background BLACK

$Job = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ArgumentList $myfile -ScriptBlock $Escribir -AsJob
    $Null = Wait-Job -Job $Job

Write-Host "Completed" 
Remove-PSSession -Session $s 
}
```

When I run the .ps1 file, I get the following error.

[image: Error]

Comment: The error says, that the file you're trying to read is not exists. Have you checked it? Do you have a proper access to it?

Comment: I'm trying to run a script from my local PC, to remote machines.
The function of this .ps1 is to read a text file from a remote PC and write it after having read it in a shared network. I run the .ps1 from my local pc,
And it works if I do it from my local PC to the shared one works, if I do it from the shared to remote PC it works, from shared to shared it works, but in the only case what I get error is that of the remote PC to shared network.

Comment: Anyway, the file your script is trying to read is not available. You should check if the file is on place before reading it.